# Proving a statement about two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ over the same alpabet

Tags: automata, regular-language, finite-automata

Given the alphabet $\Sigma$ and the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ over the given alphabet I was asked to prove/disprove the next statement:
$$ (L_1 \cup L_2)^* = L_1^* \circ L_2^*$$

I've run a few examples and I'm pretty sure that the statement is correct. I'd like some help on hints/clues on how to prove it :) I know that I need to prove that both of the sets are equal but I'm struggling with the formality involved.

Comment: Did you look at an example like $a_1b_2c_1d_2$ (where $a_1 \in L_1$, $b_2 \in L_2$ etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest counter-example is $L_1=\{0\}$ and $L_2=\{1\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I must have misunderstood what it is that the operator does :)